# List of tasks starts them synchronously - I would like them to start all at once

Tags: c#, task

```
private async Task MainTask(CancellationToken token)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    do
    {
        var data = StaticVariables.AllData;

        foreach (var dataPiece in data)
        {
            tasks.Add((new Task(() => DoSomething(data))));
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(tasks, task => task.Start());
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        tasks.Clear();
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    } while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);
}
```

The above function is supposed to start a number of `DoSomething(task)` methods and run them at the same time. `DoSomething` has a timeout of 2 sec before it returns `false`. After some testing, it seems that the part between

`await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

and

`tasks.Clear()`

is taking roughly 2 sec * number of tasks. So it would seem they do it like that:

- Start task
- do it or abort after 2 sec
- start next task
- ...

How could I do it so that they all start at the same time and perform their operations simultaneously?

**EDIT**

Doing it like so:

`await Task.WhenAll(data.Select(dataPiece => Task.Run(() => DoSomething(dataPiece)))`

results in horrible performance (around 25 sec to complete the old code, 115 sec to complete this)

Comment: Using `Parallel.ForEach` to run tasks looks like an overkill. So, you run N threads with `Parallel` and tell every thread to run an asynchronous `Task` in another separate thread. Either use `Parallel.ForEach` or create an array of `Task` and wait for their completion. Imho.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev so I should do away with `Parallel` and do something like `await tasks.Add(DoSomething(data))` and finally `await task.WhenAll(Tasks)` ?

Comment: Can't you just `tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething(data/*or dataPiece*/));` inside the loop? Your way of spawning the tasks and then activating them looks strange to me.

Comment: @grek40 That was what I tried earlier, and it too started task one after th other, not all at once, that's why I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: The result might heavily rely on the content of `DoSomething`... if it's bound on some limited resource, of course it won't get faster when multiple tasks are involved.

Comment: `DoSomething` basically updates a label text, each `DoSomething ` operates on a different label.

Comment: So, why/how does `DoSomething` take 2 seconds to complete?

Comment: It pings LAN adress (each label pings different one) for a text, if it get it within 2 seconds, it updates it, if not, it just returns false and stops trying.

Comment: So, lets not get off tracks... maybe this Q/A can be adjusted to your needs? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25452981/5265292 just introduce a timeout when waiting for the ping tasks.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in `DoSomething`. On a side note, you should never, *ever* use the task constructor or `Start`. `Task.Run` is the appropriate tool in this case.

Comment: @StephenCleary I'm gonna do a small edit to show what I've tried earlier.

Comment: @Janushoff regarding your edit: since you are passing the result of `Select` to `Task.WhenAll`, it will follow deferred execution. Meaning, if the implementation of `Task.WhenAll` is iterating the tasks and waits each one until it's complete, task 2 will never start before task 1 completes. Try `await Task.WhenAll(data.Select(dataPiece => Task.Run(() => DoSomething(dataPiece)).ToList())` instead, it should bring performance similar to the loop.

Comment: Your real problem is still, you have a synchronous method `DoSomething` to perform inherently async work (Ping & wait for response). If you redesign `DoSomething`, .Net will be able to have much better task management inside the worker threads because all the tasks will idle-wait most of the time anyway. Few comments back I already posted a link related to pinging async.

Comment: @grek40 Yes I saw that, and my explanation of `DoSomething` might not be entirely accurate. You posts have already helped me cut execution time in half so if you would compose an aswer out of your comments I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should utilize `Task.Run` instead of creating and starting tasks in separate steps.

You can do so inside the loop or Linq style. If you use Linq, just ensure that you are not stuck with deferred execution, where the second task only starts after the first one is completed. Create a list, array or some other persistent collection of your selected tasks:

```
await Task.WhenAll(data.Select(dataPiece => Task.Run(() => DoSomething(dataPiece)).ToList());
```

The other problem is with the content of `DoSomething`. As long as this is a synchronous method, it will block its executing thread until it is done. For an inherently asynchronous operation (like pinging some network address), redesigning the method can prevent this thread blocking behavior.

Another option, as answered by Matthew Watson is to increase the amount of available threads, so each task can run in its own thread. This is not the best option, but if you have many tasks that have long blocking time without doing actual work, more threads will help to get the work done.

More threads will not help if the tasks are actually using the available physical resources, CPU or IO bound work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are seeing here is due to the fact that the thread pool maintains a minimum number of threads ready to run. If the thread pool needs to create more threads than that minimum, it introduces a deliberate 1 second delay between creating each new thread.

This is done to prevent things like "thread stampedes" from swamping the system with many simultaneous thread creations.

You can change the minimum thread limit using [the ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads(v=vs.110).aspx). However, it is not recommended to do this, since it is subverting the expected thread pool operation and may cause other processes to slow down.

If you really must do it though, here's an example console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        static void Main()
        {
            runTasks();
            setMinThreadPoolThreads(30);
            runTasks();
        }

        static void setMinThreadPoolThreads(int count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nSetting min thread pool threads to {0}.\n", count);
            int workerThreads, completionPortThreads;
            ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);
            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(count, completionPortThreads);
        }

        static void runTasks()
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine("\nStarting tasks.");
            var task = test(20);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for tasks to finish.");
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished after " + sw.Elapsed);
        }

        static async Task test(int n)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(new Action(task)));

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        static void task()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task starting at time " + sw.Elapsed);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Task stopping at time " + sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

If you run it, you'll see from the output that running `test()` before setting the minimum thread pool size the tasks will take around 10 seconds (and you'll see the delay between the task start times increases after the first few tasks).

After setting the minimum thread pool threads to 30, the delay between new tasks starting is much shorter, and the overall time to run `test()` drops to around 5 seconds (on my PC - yours may be different!).

However, I just want to reiterate that setting the minimum thread pool size is not a normal thing to do, and should be approached with caution. As the Microsoft documentation says:

> By default, the minimum number of threads is set to the number of processors on a system. You can use the SetMinThreads method to increase the minimum number of threads. However, unnecessarily increasing these values can cause performance problems. If too many tasks start at the same time, all of them might appear to be slow. In most cases, the thread pool will perform better with its own algorithm for allocating threads. Reducing the minimum to less than the number of processors can also hurt performance.

Comment: The maximum number of tasks started by my function is <20, so I don't know if that's the problem. I'll check and read about your answer though, thanks!